# Why return does not exit a process in xv6?

Tags: c, xv6

Here is my code for user/sleep.c:

```
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "user/user.h"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (argc < 2)
        {
                printf("You have forgotten to pass an argument.");
                exit(1);
        }
        int arg = atoi(argv[1]);
        sleep(arg);
        exit(0);
        // return 0;
}
```

All is fine but with the return 0 instead of exit(0), I get the following error:

```
usertrap(): unexpected scause 0x000000000000000d pid=4
            sepc=0x00000000000000f6 stval=0x0000000000003008
```

Why is that?

Comment: @hyde `xv6` is not standard on these points. And the default compilation options already include `-Wall` and `-Werror`. see [Makefile](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/Makefile)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `xv6` is not standard on this point:

see https://tnallen.people.clemson.edu/2019/03/04/intro-to-xv6.html

> **Returning after main is a special case that is not supported in XV6**, so just remember to always exit() at the end of main instead of return. Otherwise, you will get a “trap 14,” which in this case is XV6-speak for “Segmentation Fault.” Finally, notice that our headers are different. There is no #include <stdio.h> as you might be used to. Again, this is because the standard library is different. Check out these headers to see what kind of user utilities you have available.

---

So why did we need `exit()` in xv6?

Because, when building a program with `gcc` for linux for instance, the tool chain add the required `exit` call: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0

In short, on linux, your program don't start at `main` but at `start`:

```c
void start(void) {
    /* get argc, argv, env) */

    int r = main(argc, argv, envp);  /*  << start calls the actual main */

    exit(r);
}
```

On xv6, on contrary, the real starting point is `main` when OS try to return from `main`, it has no address to pop what cause a segfault