# Writing to file descriptor in pipe is wrong when trying to solve 6.828 pingpong problem

Tags: c, pipe

**[BackGround](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2021/labs/util.html):**
Write a program that uses UNIX system calls to ''ping-pong'' a byte between two processes over a pair of pipes, one for each direction.

The parent should send a byte to the child; the child should print
`<pid>: received ping`, where pid is its process ID, write the byte on the pipe to the parent, and exit;

the parent should read the byte from the child, print
`<pid>: received pong`, and exit.

**Code to Solve**:

```c
#include "kernel/types.h"
#include "kernel/stat.h"
#include "user.h"

void main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int pid;
    int file_desc[2];
    
    char *parent_msg = "parent_msg";
    char *child_msg = "child_msg";

    if(pipe(file_desc) < 0){
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if(0 > (pid = fork())){
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid > 0){
        // parent process
        char* buffer = malloc(strlen(child_msg) + 1);

        if (write(file_desc[1], parent_msg, sizeof(parent_msg)) != 1){
            fprintf(2, "Can't write to child\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(file_desc[1]);

        // wait child to receive from parent
        wait(0);

        if (read(file_desc[0], buffer, sizeof(child_msg)) != 1){
            fprintf(2, "Can't read from child\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(file_desc[0]);
        printf("%d received pong\n", getpid());

    } else{
        // child process
        char* buffer = malloc(strlen(parent_msg) + 1);

        if (read(file_desc[0], buffer, sizeof(parent_msg)) != 1){
            fprintf(2, "Can't read from parent\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("%d received ping\n", getpid());
        close(file_desc[0]);

        if (write(file_desc[1], child_msg, sizeof(child_msg)) != 1){
            fprintf(2, "Can't write to parent\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        close(file_desc[1]);
    }
}
```

**Problem I met:**
When I tried to run this program, terminal in xv6 start to pop message like:

```
$ pingpong
Can't write Can't read from parent
to child
```

I guess there must be something wrong with this code:

```
write(file_desc[1], parent_msg, 11) != 1
```

But I don't know what is wrong with it. Can someone explain which part is wrong?

**Modified Correct Solution:**

1. read and write successfully return bytes is wrong, modified to `sizeof(msg)`
2. [Add exit(0) in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71583679/why-return-does-not-exit-a-process-in-xv6)
3. stderr is not recognized in xv6 system so I still remain "2" in fprintf

```c
    #include "kernel/types.h"
    #include "kernel/stat.h"
    #include "user.h"
    
    void main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        int pid;
        int file_desc[2];
        
        char *parent_msg = "parent_msg";
        char *child_msg = "child_msg";
    
        if(pipe(file_desc) < 0){
            exit(1);
        }
        
        if(0 > (pid = fork())){
            exit(1);
        }
    
        if(pid > 0){
            // parent process
            char* buffer = malloc(strlen(child_msg) + 1);
    
            if (write(file_desc[1], parent_msg, sizeof(parent_msg)) != sizeof(parent_msg)){
                fprintf(2, "Can't write to child\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            close(file_desc[1]);
    
            // wait child to receive from parent
            wait(0);
    
            if (read(file_desc[0], buffer, sizeof(child_msg)) != sizeof(child_msg)){
                fprintf(2, "Can't read from child\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            close(file_desc[0]);
            printf("%d received pong\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
    
        } else{
            // child process
            char* buffer = malloc(strlen(parent_msg) + 1);
    
            if (read(file_desc[0], buffer, sizeof(parent_msg)) != sizeof(parent_msg)){
                fprintf(2, "Can't read from parent\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("%d received ping\n", getpid());
            close(file_desc[0]);
    
            if (write(file_desc[1], child_msg, sizeof(child_msg)) != sizeof(child_msg)){
                fprintf(2, "Can't write to parent\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            close(file_desc[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (read(file_desc[0], buffer, sizeof(parent_msg)) != 1){` Why would you ever get a return value of `1` if you want to read 11 bytes? Same for `write`

Comment: `fprintf(2, "Can't write to child\n");` The first parameter is supposed to be a `FILE*`. Use `stderr` instead of 2.

Comment: As it says in the problem description, you need to use a "pair of pipes". You have only created one pipe.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. I give it a try.@Gerhardh

Comment: @IanAbbott I think fork has already make a copy of pipe. one in parent and another in child

Comment: No, `fork()` only copies the file descriptors, creating new references to the "open file descriptions" similar to `dup()`. It does not create a new pipe.

Comment: 1.When you get an error from a system call, print the error. Not some message of your own devising. Print `errno` or use `perror()` or the result of `strerror()`. 2. `read()` can return (a) -1 (b) zero or (3) a positive number. It is *impossible* to write correct read code without storing the result into a variable and testing it for all three cases. In this case you had no valid reason for expecting a return value of 1 in the first place, but the structure of your code makes it impossible to handle any of the possible conditions correctly. Don't write code like this.

Comment: Why do you include those kernel headers? You should use `stdio.h`. It will also provide `stderr`

Comment: @user207421 Good suggestion. What if one end send a random string through a pipe, how do I judge the intergrity on the read side. Maybe also include the expected number of bytes from write side, read the expected bytes first and then judge this random string

Comment: You can't 'judge the integrity on the read side'. All you can know is how many bytes were transmitted, and whether there was an error, which may not show up immediatey. And TCP offers nothing that correlates the number of bytes written with the number of bytes read per read, other than in the absence of errors they should tally over the life of the connection. TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol.